# Time difference between 2 consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has 'employee name', 'date: Date on which reading was taken', 'time: Time at which reading was taken'. I want to calculate the time difference between consecutive rows.

The problem I am facing is, I want to take time difference for a particular day. I don't want to take a difference between the reading of two different date.

I have tried this, but it is calculating the difference between time of two different dates.

```
dataFrame['Time_diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(dataFrame['Time'].astype(str)).diff(+1).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Could you give examples of how your data looks and how you want the output to be?

Comment: i have a column which has time, date, asset.. i want to create a column with the difference of two consecutive rows of time. but i dont want difference between time at which date changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
print (dataFrame)
         date      Time
0  2019-06-08  12:30:01
1  2019-06-08  13:30:01
2  2019-06-09  14:30:01
3  2019-06-09  16:30:01

dataFrame['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(dataFrame['Time'].astype(str))

#if necessary
#dataFrame = dataFrame.sort_values(['date','Time'])

dataFrame['Time_diff'] = dataFrame.groupby('date')['Time'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
print (dataFrame)
         date     Time  Time_diff
0  2019-06-08 12:30:01        NaN
1  2019-06-08 13:30:01     3600.0
2  2019-06-09 14:30:01        NaN
3  2019-06-09 16:30:01     7200.0
```

Comment: I tried this. it throws an error ''DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt''. i have imported datetime as dt as well.

Comment: @ShravanK - What is `print (dataFrame.info())` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> columns are non-null object

Comment: Can you add all output?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3381 entries, 0 to 3380
Data columns (total 15 columns):
customer       3381 non-null object
site           3381 non-null object
department     3381 non-null object
assettype      3381 non-null object
assetcode      3381 non-null object
asset          3381 non-null object
timestamp      3381 non-null object
groupid        3381 non-null object
description    3381 non-null object
component      3381 non-null object

Comment: tag            3381 non-null object
value          3381 non-null float64
unit           3381 non-null object
Date           3381 non-null object
Time           3381 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(14)
memory usage: 396.3+ KB

Comment: @ShravanK - Can you add some data sample, like `print (df[['Time','date']].head())` to question?

Comment: Time        Date
3379  12:30:01  2019-06-08
3380  12:30:01  2019-06-08
3377  12:30:07  2019-06-08
3378  12:30:07  2019-06-08
3375  12:30:12  2019-06-08

Comment: i have similar data with more rows. after some observation the date changes.

Comment: @ShravanK - tested with sample data in my answer and working nice.

Comment: how can i contact u?

Comment: @ShravanK - Sure, my email is in my profile, ony run code

Comment: i just dropped u a mail buddy

Comment: @ShravanK - Error is clean, remove double `[]` from `dataFrame.groupby('date')[['Time']].diff()` to `dataFrame.groupby('date')['Time'].diff()`

Comment: @ShravanK - If double `[]` get one column DataFrame, no Series, so raised error.